# Follow register changes with gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, gdbserver

How can I follow on changes in specific registers using GDB?

I want to write a log each instruction's address that changed the value on this register

How can I do that using GDB ?

Comment: So `watch $YOUR_REGISTER` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @ssbssa `watch` is good , but I need to continue each time the process manually , I want only write to log the address of instruction that makes the change

Comment: Add [commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html), in this case `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write a log each instruction's address that changed the value on this register

The only way to do this is to single-step the program, compare values of registers to previously-saved values, and print *previous* value of instruction pointer if the value of the register of interest has changed.

You can automate this by using GDB embedded Python, but even with automation this will be impractically slow for any non-trivial program (as would single-stepping without actually doing anything between the steps).

P.S. Depending on what *actual* problem you are trying to solve (see http://xyproblem.info), more practical solutions may exist.